# Find 2nd largest element. Two variables vs priority queue for interview

Tags: arrays, algorithm, heap

A classical interview problem is "Find 2nd largest element in an array".

The most straight forward way would be to keep track of variables like `largest`, `secondLargest`, and iterate over, O(n) time complexity, and O(1) space complexity.

Another option would be to keep priority queue implemented by using heap size 2 (or K), and get the elements the heap, after you iterate. For each iteration, I am adding to queue size of 2, so the time complexity is O(n*log(K)), where K is 2, so it is technically O(n).

Here is argument from each side:

Two variables:

- simple for loop
- thinking about going beyond k=2 is a "You Aren't Gonna Need It (YAGNI)" problem.
- Some O(n) are better solutions, if it requires less computations.

Priority queue:

- overhead of heap exists and it affects the coefficient in the time complexity. But we drop constants in complexity analysis, so it is technically a linear solution.
- But can be easily modified for find kth largest element.
- It isn't that much more difficult to implement it.

My point of view is that the two variables version is definitely more performant and simple for this specific question, but I have slight preference toward the heap version because even with some expense and extra code, it can be easily scaled. I don't think the scope is big enough to consider using heap a "YAGNI".

Assuming back and forth discussion has been done during the interview, which one would you prefer?

Edit: As mentioned in the comments/answer section, I have specified priority queue with heap implementation.

Comment: Keeping track of the largest and second largest *is* making a priority queue of size 2.

Comment: *"which one would you prefer?"*: preference questions are off topic here as they are largely a matter of opinion -- and you are essentially asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition for priority queue, it basically states:

> A priority queue is a special type of queue in which each element is associated with a priority value

Note that no particular data structure is mentioned to implement the priority queue. It is generally done using a heap (like you have assumed in your statement), but that's not always true (here's a [priority queue using linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-using-linked-list/)). As Matt has pointed out in his comment, keeping a track of the largest and second largest element is the same thing as having a priority queue of size 2.